# Django - Q lookup search is slow for over a million records in MySQL

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application which involves a search in the database table and filters out all the results and data.

> models.py

```
class TableData(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True, null=False)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    field5 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field6 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field7 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, default='200')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 254, unique=True)
    search_qs = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='N/A')
```

> views.py

```
def search(request):
    searchquery = request.GET.get("q")
    if searchquery:
        all_queryset_list = TableData.objects.all()

        queryset_list = all_queryset_list.filter(Q(search_qs__icontains=searchquery) | 
                                                 Q(field1__icontains=searchquery))

        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 25)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        searchres = paginator.get_page(page)
        res_count = queryset_list.count()


    context = {
        'searchres': searchres,
        'res_count': res_count,
    }
    return render(request, 'results.html', context)
```

Here everything works fine as expected, but the searched results takes too much of time for the table having over a million records.

**How can I optimize the query to get the results faster ?**

Really appreciate for anyone who can help me this.

Comment: Why you are using Q filter when there is only one field to seach.
Q is used to do OR query between fields.
and for query i think its in optimized state. but you can do like this.
`queryset_list = TableData.objects.filter(search_qs__icontains=searchquery)`

Comment: Your view can break if there is no searchquery. since res_count = queryset_list.count() is inside if condition and you are accessing it on outside of if statement. 
try adding: `if queryset_list: res_count = queryset_list.count()  else: res_count = 0`

Comment: @jeevu94 Thanks for the suggestion. Also, the query is still taking a longer time than expected. 

Is there anything else I can do to run the query faster?

Comment: Im not Master in Django but i think its in optimized state. But really curious and waiting for any answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could speed up the lookup by adding a [database index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#:%7E:text=A%20database%20index%20is%20a,maintain%20the%20index%20data%20structure.) for your table column, by default, only the primary key is indexed.

This could be achieved either by [`index meta option`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#indexes)

```
class TableData(models.Model):
    ...
    search_qs = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='N/A')

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['search_qs']),
        ]
```

Or explicitly specify [`db_index=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) in that column.

```
class TableData(models.Model):
    ...
    search_qs = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='N/A', db_index=True)
```

Remember to `makemigrations` after your changes

Comment: Tried, maybe this thing was effective but not in my case.
The searched result is still slow.